# Specifiying path in POM for Maven

Tags: java, maven

When ever i package my Application, it gets placed in target directory. Instead i want to choose tomcat WebApps directory. How to specify that in POM.xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [tomcat plugin](http://mojohaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/deployment.html):

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
                <warFile>path/to/my/warFile.war</warFile>
        </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: C:\Tomcat 5.5\webapps how should i specify this there.

Answer (score 1):

```
   <build>
      <directory>${custom.build.directory}</directory>
    </build>
    <properties>

      <custom.build.directory>target</custom.build.directory>
    </properties>
```

In your settings.xml:

```
    <properties>
      <!-- Personal overridden value, perhaps profile-specific -->
      <custom.build.directory>/your/dir/</custom.build.directory>
    </properties>
```